# Are Codeigniter Active Records automatically escaped?

Tags: php, codeigniter

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Is everything automatically escaped for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the notes on the exact page you linked to specify:

> Note: All values are escaped
>   automatically producing safer queries.

Comment: Sorry, I read multiple instances of all values are escaped so I thought they only applied to that function only.

Answer (score 1):

> It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system.

was it so hard to search for "escape" substring on that page?